# Escaping from "inout hell"

Tags: d

I have some very simple code that refuses to compile:

```
struct Wrapper(T)
{
    T t;

    bool opEquals(inout(Wrapper) other) inout
    {
        return t == other.t;
    }

    bool opEquals(inout(T) val) inout
    {
        return t == val;
    }
}

struct Test
{
    bool opEquals(Test t)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

void main()
{
    Wrapper!Test a, b;

    assert(a == b);

    //Error: inout method Test.opEquals is not 
    //callable using a mutable object
    assert(a == Test());
}
```

Now, I know the problem, which is that `Test` does not defin an `inout` `opEquals`. However, defining another mutable version of `opEquals` in `Test` does not fix this problem, as the compiler just ignores it and calls the `inout` version regardless. Is there any way for me to fix this problem without resorting to defining an `opEquals` overload for mutable, `const`, and `immutable`?

Comment: Your second `opEquals` method in `Wrapper` is spelled incorrectly. Also because `opEquals` doesn't modify its argument, you can just make it `const`, and it will work on both mutable and immutable types.

Comment: I believe the problem is with the fact that I have marked `Wrapper.opEquals` as `inout`, rather than it being that the argument is marked as `inout`. Removing `inout` from the method causes it to compile, but then it would not work if I created an `immutable` or `const` `Wrapper`.

Comment: It works if you make `opEquals` const, which you should do anyway because `opEquals` shouldn't be modifying anything. http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/6cab4a419488

Comment: You're missing the crucial piece with your example: a user-defined type with elaborate `opEquals`. See my modification:

http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/ef0ac35dd3b3

Comment: You probably need to use `static if` to see if the wrapped type's `opEquals` is const, and define a mutable or const `opEquals` based on that (inout is more about transferring const/immutable to the return type, which you don't need for booleans). Or make Test's `opEquals` const, or use `alias t this;`

Comment: "You probably need to use `static if`..." That's exactly what I want to avoid, however. Branching on the constness of the wrapped type's `opEquals` is something I thought `inout` should be used to fix.

Comment: @Meta All `inout` is for is making it so that you can make the constness of the return type match that of a parameter without resorting to templates (since with `const`, you lose the constness of the parameter and just always get `const` for the return type). Within the function, `inout` is basically the same as `const` with all of the restrictions that come with it. So, it's pointless to make a function `inout` unless you're trying to affect the return type. There is no way to make it so that you can call a mutable function on an object that is not mutable.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis How is this worked around in Phobos? Having a user-defined type with only mutable opEquals pretty much precludes any inout/const/immutable wrapper types from working with that user-defined type.

Comment: @Meta If `const` is going to be forwarded, it needs to be tested for with `static if`, and the functions in question need to be duplicated. Some of Phobos does that, but far too often, the constness simply isn't forwarded. But most of the places in Phobos where it would apply would be ranges, and `const` ranges are useless, so forwarding the constness of functions like `front` or `empty` doesn't really do much for you anyway. It's possible to make `const` ranges work by making it so that `save` returns a tail-const variant of the range, but it's a pain, and Phobos doesn't do it currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `inout` is for is making it so that the constness of the return type can match that of a function argument. If you have

```
const(Foo) bar(const(Foo) f) {
{
    //...
    return f;
}
```

and you pass a `mutable` or `immutable` object to `bar`, you end up with a `const` object returned, whereas if you use `inout`

```
inout(Foo) bar(inout(Foo) f) {
{
    //...
    return f;
}
```

the return type has the same constness as the argument passed to `f`. Either way, within the function, `f` is effectively treated as `const`. You can only call `const` and `inout` functions on it. So, making `opEquals` `inout` is pointless, because it doesn't return any of its arguments. It's the same as making it `const`.

Your fundamental problem here is that you're trying to call a mutable function on a `const` object. And that's not legal, because it violates `const`. You have one of two options:

1. Make `Wrapper`'s `opEquals` mutable. Then it can call `opEquals` when `T`'s `opEquals` is mutable.
2. Use `static if` to define `opEquals` differently depending on how `T` defined `opEquals`.

There is no way to forward the constness of `opEquals` from `T` to `Wrapper` without doing it explicitly with `static if`. e.g.

```
struct Wrapper(T)
{
    T t;

    static if(is(typeof({const T t; t == t;})))
    {
        bool opEquals(const Wrapper other) const
        {
            return t == other.t;
        }

        bool opEquals(const T val) const
        {
            return t == val;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        bool opEquals(Wrapper other)
        {
            return t == other.t;
        }

        bool opEquals(T val)
        {
            return t == val;
        }
    }
}
```

Because `Wrapper` is a template, `pure`, `nothrow`, and `@safe` will be inferred on its functions, but there is no attribute inference for `const`, `inout`, or `immutable`.

Comment: My confusion stems from the mistaken assumption that `bool opEquals inout` should act as mutable when `Wrapper` is mutable. I think I have a good understanding now for exactly why that won't work... This is really all one big headache if you want your type to work correctly with any "constness".

Comment: @Meta Yes, a way to forward constness would be useful, but exactly how that should work becomes an interesting question. It's been discussed before but not yet gone anywhere. Fortunately, it really only comes up when wrapping types, and that happens primarily with ranges, and ranges and` const` interact badly enough that the lack of `const` on functions like `front` and `empty` hasn't really mattered.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `inout`. The compiler infers attributes like `const` automatically for templates.

You're not using `inout` for its intended purpose anyway; [`inout`](http://dlang.org/function.html#inout-functions) is meant for transferring mutable, const, or immutable to a function's return type based on its parameters. The function body has to assume the worst (const), so it can't call non-constant methods.

Note that since, in your example, `Test.opEquals` isn't `const`, it can only be called on a mutable object. Also note that in D, `const` is transitive, so `const(Wrapper!Test)` is the same as `const(Wrapper!(const(Test)))`. So no matter what, you can't call `Test.opEquals` on a const/immutable object (even in a wrapper) unless you make it `const`.

Comment: I cannot remove `inout` from `opEquals`, as then it will not work with `immutable` or `const` objects. Let's drop down to `const` so I can better illustrate my problem. Looking at the [following code](http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/a3242543f31e), do you understand why it doesn't compile, and why I can't  just remove `inout` from `Wrapper.opEquals`?

Comment: @Meta It can't compile because `Test.opEquals` isn't `const`. It wouldn't work without the wrapper either. `assert(const(Test)() == const(Test)())`

Comment: Yes, so we're back to my original question. I guess this means that the answer is "no".

Comment: @Meta See edit; you're trying to call `Test.opEquals` on a const object, but `Test.opEquals` isn't const. It has nothing to do with your wrapper or `inout`.